# Ioredis: When reconnecting redis via connect() , calling connect doesn't reset retry times to 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, backend, ioredis

I have following options set when connecting to Redis

```
var client = new Redis({
  port: 63xx, // Redis port
  host: REDISHOST, // Redis host
  family: 4, // 4 (IPv4) or 6 (IPv6)
  db: 0,
  lazyConnect: true,
  // The milliseconds before a timeout occurs during the initial connection to the Redis server.
  connectTimeout: 3000,

  retryStrategy: function (times) {

    if (times > 3) {
      logger.error("redisRetryError", 'Redis reconnect exhausted after 3 retries.');
      return null;
    }

    return 200;

  }

});
```

Later on, I am exporting this client throughout project for redis queries.
The issue is when *Request 1* comes and there is some issue with redis, it tries to auto-connect for 4 times(+1 for initial try). Then throws error which is handled.
So for now times variable(used in retrystrategy()) will have 4 as value.

Next time when *Request 2* comes and we see redis is disconnected so we reconnect using client.connect() method:

```
static async getData(key) {

        try {

            // if connection is ended then we are trying to reconnect it.
            if (client.status === 'end') {
                await logger.warning(`reconnectingRedis`, 'Redis is not connected. Trying to reconnect to Redis!');
                await client.connect();
            }

            let output = await client.get(key);

            return JSON.parse(output);

        } catch (error) {
            ApiError.throw(error, errorCode.REDIS_GET_ERROR_CODE);
        }

    }
```

this time redis tries to reconnect but it doesn't resets the times variable used in retrystrategy(), So this variable now have 5.
And if this attempt too fails, retrystrategy() just throws error as `times > 3`

So effectively *Request 1* gets 4 tries and *Request 2* gets only 1

How can I fix this, So that *Request 2* also gets 4 tries ?

Comment: @eol Included code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue I changed retryStrategy function used while creating redis in following way:

```
retryStrategy: function (times) {

    if (times % 4 ==0) { 
      logger.error("redisRetryError", 'Redis reconnect exhausted after 3 retries.');
      return null;
    }

    return 200;

  }
```

**Notice** I took mod 4 of times variable and Doing so we will always get a value in range of 0-3.

So for request 2 when times variable has 5, its mod 4 will give 1 and will be tried,
next time times will be 6, So mode 4 is 2 and will be tried and so on. Till it becomes 8, In this case, mod 4 will give 0 and retry stops.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added more information to the answer